Geting Error "mapbox::util::bad_variant_access" while cluster is enable for the "Point" and "Polygon" geo json data
Mapbox Implementation
Mapbox
Mapbox Version
default
React Native Version
0.71.8
Platform
iOS, Android
@rnmapbox/maps version
10.1.31
Sample Code
import MapboxGL, { MapView } from "@rnmapbox/maps";
import React from "react";

const MapScreen = () => {
  const GEO_JSON = [
    //link attched in description
  ];

  return (
    <MapView requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
        id="hangoutMarkers"
        onPress={() => {}}
        cluster
        clusterRadius={50}
        clusterMaxZoomLevel={16}
        shape={GEO_JSON}
      >
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
          id="singlePoint"
          filter={["==", ["geometry-type"], "Point"]}
          style={{
            iconImage: ["get", "icon"],
            iconSize: 0.2,
            iconAllowOverlap: false,
          }}
        />
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
          filter={["==", ["geometry-type"], "Point"]}
          id="pointCount"
          style={{
            textField: [
              "format",
              ["concat", ["get", "point_count"], "\n"],
              {},
              ["concat"],
              { "font-scale": 0.8 },
            ],
            textSize: 12,
            textPitchAlignment: "map",
          }}
        />
        <MapboxGL.CircleLayer
          id="clusteredPoints"
          belowLayerID="pointCount"
          filter={["has", "point_count"]}
          // style={layerStyles.clusteredPoints}
        />
        <MapboxGL.FillLayer
          id="polygonFillLayer"
          filter={["==", ["geometry-type"], "Polygon"]}
          style={{
            fillColor: "black",
          }}
        />
        <MapboxGL.LineLayer
          id="polygonLineLayer"
          filter={["==", ["geometry-type"], "Polygon"]}
          style={{
            lineColor: "black",
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineDasharray: [1, 0],
          }}
        />
      </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default MapScreen



Geo Json link https://drive.google.com/file/d/17vgyPMDGxT_4uIVBndTXmh0WfIDb3vZn/view?usp=sharing
Lib used:
"@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.16.1"
"@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.31"
When multi type features is there  (Point and Polygon) in GEO JSON and clustering is enable from the  MapboxGL.ShapeSource then App going to crash and giving error for the "bad variant access". When I am commenting the clustering props in the  MapboxGL.ShapeSource then is working and show the Point and Polygon view on the Map view.
Expecting : Clustering should work with the "Point" and "Polygon".
